# Основной цикл в Javascript-машине

Tags: javascript, циклы

Был мне озвучен данный вопрос, но не смог найти нигде на него ответа,гугл просто находить информацию по циклам... Расскажите, пожалуйста, что такое основной цикл в Javascript-машине.

Comment: [Концепция жизненного цикла](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Grundy оформите свой комментарий как ответ